# Using Ubuntu 13.10 aside Windows 8 fast boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, ntfs

I've been looking around for mounting ntfs partition on Ubuntu with Windows 8 dual boot. I've found that the Fast Boot feature on W8 makes impossible to mount any ntfs in the same system.

So, my question is if there is any possibility to mount ntfs partition and still using Windows 8 Fast Boot feature to speed up boots? I just don't want to loose boot speed for mounting ntfs partitions.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't and neither you should.

The fastboot feature is called as hybrid shutdown. It can be seen as partial hibernation and partial shut down. In simple words, It takes a snapshot of current memory and stores to disk to be used on next start up. A good explanation can be found here - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/

So if it is allowed to make changes to the ntfs file system by any means, on next start up win 8 won't able to know what changes were made. Because it restores from a snapshot which was made earlier. Thus leading to data corruption. To prevent this ntfs 3g driver developers made [modifications](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html) that causes NTFS partitions be mountable as read-only if the driver detects a Windows system with active Fast Startup.