# Ubuntu 14.04 No Sound from Speaker

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

This appears to be a popular topic recently so appologies for only adding to it.

I have recently dual booted a Dell Inspiron 7000 series with Ubuntu 14.04. The sound initially worked but after some time, the speakers stopped working. Its worth noting that the headphone jack continued to worked fine.

After some searching, I managed to get it working again by purging and re-installing pulseadio and alsa. However, after another few days, the speakers stopped working again. This time, purging and re-installing pulseaudio and alsa did not work.

I have checked alsamixer and nothing is muted. I have installed some additional drivers as recommended in some threads but I forget which ones.

Interesting thing is, (I think) [alsainfo](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ab743b7beda427b9d73d0640aa17cc83c1646e29) says my master if off:

> !!-------Mixer controls for card 1 [PCH]
>
> Card hw:1 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0614000 irq 60' 
>   ... Simple mixer control 'Master',0

But alsamixer says it is not:

**Sorry, I haven't got enough reputation to post images.**

Does anybody have any advice?

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: A couple of reboots later and it has decided to start working again. I have no idea what happened here but its working again.

Comment: If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567). If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020).

Answer (score 2):

If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567).

If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020). In this case, it is a bug that, in its nature, intermittently exists. I'm pretty sure it is a start-up bug of some sort, and have already noted it as such in the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I suggest you install pavucontrol to give you a good view of what pulseaudio thinks is going on. In alsamixer, check and make sure that the right sound card is selected.

I suggest you might try asking on the linuxmusicians forum, where the knowledge level of  linux audio is pretty high.

Comment: Yes I have tried this. Still no luck. Thnks though