# No sound devices or input devices (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: 14.04, sound

So last night I turned my laptop off to go to sleep, I then turned it on this morning only to discover I have no sound devices (input and output).

I tried `sudo Alsa force-reload`
and also tried reinstalling Alsa and Pulse Audio

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

edit: I think the problem is that pulseaudio wont load, any ideas how to fix it, tried reinstalling it already?

Comment: at first try `sudo killall pulseaudio ` then `sudo alsa force-reload`

Comment: the problem is that pulseaudio wont load at all?

Comment: If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567). If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020).