# 15.10 - Sound doesn't work, no sound devices after update restart

Tags: sound, 14.10, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I clicked on a normal system update and it asked me to reboot my computer, so I did. After the reboot, there's no sound.
Mute/unmute button doesn't do anything (even the notification for volume up/down doesn't appear). It gets weirder

This is my sound settings window. No devices are listed in Output or Input:
[Sound Settings Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUoxa.png)

When I ran VLC to see if maybe YouTube was the problem, there was a pop-up error:

> Audio output failed:
>       The audio device "default" could not be used:
>       No such file or directory.

Here's my dmesg | grep snd output:

```
[    4.536437] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3223: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.536442] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.536445] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.536447] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.536449] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    4.536452] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[    4.536455] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
[    4.536458] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.521447] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
```

And pulseaudio control (pavucontrol) only has this inside:

[Connection to PulseAudio failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnHfn.png)

"...This is likely because PULSE_SERVER or default-server in client.conf is misconfigured...."

I followed a few other posts such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193575/sound-works-but-no-device-shown-in-the-sound-settings) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500934/no-sound-devices-or-input-devices-ubuntu-14) but nothing. Something got messed up and I can't figure what it is :/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fixed it myself after following the instructions [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

It turns out something was wrong with either alsa-base or pulseaudio. purging them and reinstalling solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now the hotkeys for volume up/down won't work. I tried setting them to their defaults by

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
```

but that didn't work, so I renamed the .gconf home folder and rebooted. Everything is back in working order now :)

```
mv .gconf .gconf_backup
```