# Headphone is not working for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I just converted into ubuntu 14.04 from windows and the speakers on my laptop are working fine. Although when I tried to use my headphones the sound is still coming out from my speakers. I looked at my sound settings and I cannot find the headphones icon. Already looked through the alsamixer and set all volumes at at high and unmuted everything.

Comment: Are those headphones connected by USB or by phone jacks?

Comment: It is connected by phone jacks.

Comment: Sorry if this question, but: Is there sound coming from the headphones?

Comment: It's ok =). There is a sound coming out of the headphones. Actually when I was still using windows it is working fine. I just tried to plug it on my phone to recheck and its working.

Answer (score 2):

From Windows , do a real shutdown (not reboot) and retest.
If not ok, disable  "Fast Boot" (see [this answer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1)

Comment: I can't believe that this worked. Such a stupid-simple solution! THANKS!