# No sound in Ubuntu 14.10 on Asus laptop - dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, asus, 14.10

I have an Asus N551jk. I have dual boot on it. Sound works on Windows 8.1, but not on Ubuntu 14.10. More precise sometimes it works, but various events like a simple reboot, can make it not work again....

I followed the steps described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/541880/sound-not-working-ubuntu-14-10-pulseaudio-alsa-fixed . It worked for a while, but now it doesn't work again... Not immediately sure what's the problem.

Best regards!

Comment: Could be like http://askubuntu.com/questions/539765/headphone-is-not-working-for-ubuntu-14-04/539811#539811    : do a real shutdown from windows, simple reboot can stick soundcard

Comment: @laugeo Yes. I already did that. However it only works if I restart the computer after few minutes. When rebooting directly to Ubuntu sound still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to just close the computer (so that it goes to sleep) and open it up again, seems to solve the problem for many, includning me. havent seen a good answer to why it works yet..

I have the same issue on a Dell Latitude E7440

Comment: Simply rebooting doesn't work. However, when I restart the computer after several minutes seems to always work. Not immediately sure why that is the case.

Comment: I meant to put it to sleep, not reboot. I have the same issue from time to time and the only thing that works is put the computer to sleep and then wake it up or shutdown, remove battery and power-up.

Comment: I have actually stopped sleep by disabling it. Therefore when I shut down the laptop it actuall shuts down instead of hibernating/going to sleep and other scenarios. It seems to be an UEFI drivers problem - whereas if you reboot to fast from Windows to Ubuntu, the sounds disappears.