# HDMI is my card 0

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I am dual booting linux and windows 8 on a lenovo yoga 2  pro. My speaker volume isn't working but headphone volume works fine. Alsa controls my audio and the speaker volume is on. I found that my card 0 is HDMI and not my actual audio card. I think this may be the source of the problem but I am scared to just rename things because I am new and I will probably just break everything. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- First try this: [real shutdown from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539765/headphone-is-not-working-for-ubuntu-14-04/539811#539811)
- Then install "**Pulseaudio volume control**" (aka pavucontrol, which has more controls than standard "sound settings"):
  In the output device tab, you can select which device is the default for pulseaudio , clicking corresponding green button .
- To change order at Alsa level: run this command :
  `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
  so you can  modify alsa-base.conf:
  add this line at the end:
  `options snd-hda-intel index=1,0`
  then save file and reboot.
  (from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186597))