# Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot with windows 8. Sound doesn't work in ubuntu. I checked all answers for all similar questions but nothing helped me.

I have an *asus n-550jk notebook*.

In sound settings I can see `speakers` and `analog output`.

In PulseAudio Volume Control I can see that the volume bar is changing but there is no sound.

In `Output devices` tab of `PAVUcontrol` there are DIgital Stereo HDMI (all unplugged) and Analog Stereo (ports Speakers and Analog Output). The volume bar for analog stereo is also working.

The output for `lspci | grep -i 'audio'` is:

```
 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)

 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

The output for `aplay -l` is:

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 0/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

 card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

 card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
   Subdevices: 0/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have `alsa` and `pulseaudio` installed.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to me that you have a dualboot setup this thread might have an answer to your problem.

Right here: [No sound from laptop speakers in Ubuntu 14.04 after booting into Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1)