# rtl8723be drops wifi connection on hp pavilion notebook ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, rtl8723be

I have recently bougth a HP Pavilion Notebook and performed dual boot with ubuntu 14.04 lts and noted that no wifi networks on first boot. I've searched a lot (really) and did lots of stuff (installed lwfinger drivers, installed hanipouspilot/rtlwifi, set many options in /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf, overrided firmware file, etc) but wifi continue dropping after 15-20 mins of every boot.

Then, full of hope I upgraded to 16.04 lts but the problem persists. I've tried the same things and some others that I didn't see before, but still I can't get it working. Here are some relevant lines of syslog when the connection gets disconnected:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog

Apr 27 23:56:11 shaka-home kernel: [ 1331.653296] rtlwifi:rtl_watchdog_wq_callback():<0-0> AP off, try to reconnect now
Apr 27 23:56:11 shaka-home kernel: [ 1331.653384] wlo1: Connection to AP xx:xx:xx::2e:35 lost 
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home wpa_supplicant[927]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:2e:35 reason=4 locally_generated=1<br/>
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <warn>  [1461812178.2669] sup-iface[0xa7ae10,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812178.2731] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home wpa_supplicant[927]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919705] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919706] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919708] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919709] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919710] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919711] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919712] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919713] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.919714] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:18 shaka-home kernel: [ 1338.932853] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 27 23:56:23 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812183.1749] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 27 23:56:29 shaka-home kernel: [ 1349.698560] rtl8723be:rtl8723be_hw_init():<0-0> Init MAC failed
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <warn>  [1461812193.3567] device (wlo1): link timed out.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.3568] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [100 120 53]
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.3577] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.3582] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <warn>  [1461812193.4518] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home dbus[640]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654 <info>  [1461812193.4576] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home kernel: [ 1354.100966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Withdrawing address record for xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlo1.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.<br/>
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.5081] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1430
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.5082] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed bound -> done
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812193.5102] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home dnsmasq[1666]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.30 on wlo1.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address xxx.xxx.x.xx.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home avahi-daemon[666]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home dbus[640]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlo1]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlo1]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 27 23:56:33 shaka-home kernel: [ 1354.222325] rtl8723be:rtl8723be_hw_init():<0-0> Init MAC failed
Apr 27 23:56:35 shaka-home NetworkManager[654]: <info>  [1461812195.4756] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Apr 27 23:56:36 shaka-home kernel: [ 1357.045971] rtl8723be:rtl8723be_hw_init():<0-0> Init MAC failed
Apr 27 23:56:38 shaka-home whoopsie[686]: [23:56:38] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 27 23:56:59 shaka-home kernel: [ 1380.059272] rtl8723be:rtl8723be_hw_init():<0-0> Init MAC failed
Apr 27 23:57:32 shaka-home kernel: [ 1413.056399] rtl8723be:rtl8723be_hw_init():<0-0> Init MAC failed
```

/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf contents:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
options rtl8723be debug=1
options rtl8723be disable_watchdog=N
options rtl8723be fwlps=Y
options rtl8723be ips=Y
options rtl8723be msi=Y
options rtl8723be swenc=N
options rtl8723be swlps=N
```

Funny thing is that after connection drops I can see other networks in 16.04 but not mine, different from 14.04 that after dropping no network was available until rebooting.

Sorry for the long post. Hope you can help me to solve this annoying problem.

Kind regards 
Max

**EDIT** 
 I'd run network diagnostics and here is the link to its results:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16503095/

Thanks again!
Max

Comment: **Update:** I've set IPv6  settings to be ignored and nothing has changed...

Comment: I don't see an issue in the diagnosis results. Do you have the same problem with different access points or with Windows on the same computer? Searching for [RTL8723BE](/search?q=RTL8723BE) returned these interesting results: [1](/q/590414/175814), [2](/q/635625/175814), [3](/q/756748/175814). Could you please see if any of them help and make a note in your question of what you tried so far? Also, you should switch the wireless security mode to WPA2 if possible; WPA1 has some design flaws that leave it a little vulnerable.

Comment: Great. Thanks David. Will check the 3 links and get back to you.

Comment: Dave, I'd already checked all the solutions given in those posts some time ago and none of them worked for me. The best I've got so far is to install lwfinger driver,  set ant_sel=2 only and after every login I restart the module. Then my connection can last about 30 min aprox in most of the cases, some times this action gives me about an hour and some other times the connection doesn't drop, but as you can see drops for me are random.  About your questions: **a)yes**: I have the same problem with another access points and **b)no**: there are no problems with Windows 10 :/

Comment: I think I've solved this. Please, everyone that has windows with ubuntu with dual boot read this post (specially the first answer) http://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1
I've disabled fast boot in win10 and no more dropouts occurred.

Comment: After formatting the hdd I noticed that dropouts started to happen again... And no Windows was present anymore!! Ok, found what I think the defitive solution: I recompiled the driver located at https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new cloning the code in rock.new_btcoex branch. That definitely solved the situation: the wifi remains stable and no more dropouts occured.