# Sound not working with Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am using ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS on our embedded hardware.
The sound does not work.

the output of `lspci -v` is the following for `Audio` devices:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7430000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Not sure why there are two entries but its Intel Audio that is the actual amplifier. I was able to get the sound on our custom toolchain(derived from Suse) running on this hardware so the hardware works fine. That is for sure.

I did try uninstalling and reinstalling `alsa` and `pulseaudio` but that does not help.

I checked the mixer and the sound is not muted and the volume is at 50%.

The output of `sudo aplay -l` is :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amplifier [4.1 amplifier], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I also tried to play a sound using `aplay`:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

But nothing can be heard through speakers. No sound.

Can you suggest how to fix this and make the sound work ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't take credit for the fix. But this broke on me today. <3-3-17>

Found the answer here:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1
```

> Blockquote: It finally worked by adding the below line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file "options snd-hda-intel model=auto"