# Ubuntu 18.04 No audio from speakers. Headphones working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 18.04, speakers

I updated my Surface Pro 3 From Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 (did a clean install) and now I can only get audio when using the headphone jack. 
I have already tried all these:
[troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117842/no-sound-from-speakers-but-headphones-work)
[another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829520/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound-from-speakers-only-headphones-working)

I went back and tested the live CD and even the live cd has no audio through the speakers. so this must be related to 18.04. I never had sound issues before and under windows audio still works correctly.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

**Update:** here is my [alsa iformation](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=8bf135db52610a603014779ef24041a491c8a32d)

**Update**
HOLY CRAP...  I removed the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and now sounds works ! 
i am going to try adding line by line to see which config entry was breaking the audio

Comment: What happens if you disable "Auto-mute" in `alsamixer`

Comment: @stumblebee nothing. I tried disabling it then reconecting headphones and switching the mute on all channels. same problem

Comment: With my alc662 did not work at all. I am desperate. NO SOUND

Comment: I've disabled  "auto-mute" in `alsamixer` and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welp.... I have no idea what just happened.... but renaming /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.bk , then rebooting the computer fixed the my speaker sound issue.

I then restored line by line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, rebooting between restored lines, until all lines were back.... and ... it still worked! 
so I restored the original /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and rebooted the computer and everything was still working....
so I am not sure what the problem was but is now fixed.