# Ubuntu 18.10 Headphones/Speakers "linked" (Speakers have no sound)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

This is one of those "No Audio" problems i'm having with my old Toshiba NB500-108 netbook and it's essentially the problem described by the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829520/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound-from-speakers-only-headphones-working/929766#929766), which means that if I unmute the "Headphones" volume on ALSA the volume finally plays back from the internal speakers. Connecting and type of headphones in the jack or rebooting the system gives me no audio again until I unmute the "Headphone" profile from ALSA.

The problem arises when the command suggested for finding the mixer path:

```
pactl list | grep 'Active Port.*output.*'
```

Gives no output at all, i'm not sure if this is simply the cmd that has been removed or I have a problem with the installation.

Any way I can fix this problem?

[Here is the ALSA screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y51s6.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue myself by guessing which one would be the right path. It turned out to be:

```
analog-output-speaker
```

So, in case you are a similar problem with one of those old netbooks with Intel Atom, try to follow the solution I posted in the question and use that path.