# Ubuntu 20.04 Built-in speakers treated as headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

## Built-in Speakers treated as headphones

I recently configured dual boot with ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now I have a volume problem.

This is the default sound configuration when I boot my computer and when I unplug a headphone or any external speaker.
[image: How alsamixer appears at booting]
.

My problem is:

1. My Headphone Volume is controled by the "Headphone" device.
2. Getting sound from my headphones requires that the "Master" and "Headphone" devices be unmuted.
3. My Speaker Volume is ALSO controlled by the "Headphone" device. (The ALSA speaker volume setting suprisingly has no effect on my speaker's volume). And when I unplug a Headphone, the "Headphone" device turns to 0 volume, as it does when I turn on the pc.
4. Getting sound from my speakers requires that the "Master" and "Speaker" devices be unmuted.

So, basically I have to turn on the "Headphone" device any time I start my pc or unplug any sound device.

So it is exactly the same problem as this comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/929766/1092287, but I tried with that solution and it didn't work, it just worsened everything and I have to uninstall and reinstall alsa-base and pulseaudio

I would really appreciate it if you could give me a solution to this problem that has been driving me nuts. Thank you in advance, and tell me if you need more info about my computer or something.

Comment: This is a pretty basic question but never mind. Did you shutdown and restarted the machine. It's called 'Cold Boot'. Shutdown, unplug, plug-in, switch on. We all have the habit of closing the lid when done and open it when need to be used. This leaves the machine powered all the time though it s low powered during sleep. I know this issue would make you crazy and frustrated but if you haven't done that you may do that. Otherwise, let us know the machine configuration. When you say dual boot the other one is Windows?

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings to what you want and then storing them as default with `sudo alsactl store`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings