# No sound from laptop speakers after Ubuntu suspension

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa

Every time I (lid-closing) suspend Ubuntu, when I get back again, the volume of internal speakers do not wok. There is no sound at all. If I simply reboot into Windows (10) the problem is present there as well, and I can not play any sound.

I followed many discussions on this, in particular [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1), where are explained some of the most common workaround that I followed to partially fix the original problem (only dummy output device listed in the sound options). Now the problem of no sound appears only after the suspension. In the same discussion, it is suggested to cold shutdown the system and then boot into Windows. This "fixes" the problem, but at the next suspension of Ubuntu it reappears.

What can I do to avoid this issue after every Ubuntu suspension?

EDIT: to update and add some more info to this not yet solved issue:

```
:~$ dpkg -l *alsa*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  alsa           <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  alsa-base      1.0.25+dfsg- all          ALSA driver configuration files
un  alsa-oss       <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  alsa-utils     1.1.0-0ubunt amd64        Utilities for configuring and usi
un  bluez-alsa     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gstreamer1.0-a 1.8.2-1ubunt amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
un  libesd-alsa0   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libsdl1.2debia <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: If you first boot into Windows before Ubuntu does it occur ?

Comment: @George, nope, it doesnt.

Comment: when this occurs do `sudo lshw | grep multimedia` to see if the device shows up

Comment: @George, what should be the standard/expected output of that line?

Comment: You should see something like this `*-multimedia:0`

Comment: What about `*-multimedia UNCLAIMED` (tried when the issue has not raised yet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50880/discussion-between-george-and-py-ser).