# I can't hear voice after I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, sound

My pc is Dell Latitude E5470 and the original system version is 14.04LTS. When I upgraded to 16.04LTS, I could't hear voice. The following are pictures about my pc sound setting:

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me what's the cause? Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to fix a very similar issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/859849/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-after-ubuntu-suspension. All I can say for the moment is that forcing shutdown (hold the power button) and restart seem to temporarily fix the problem.

Comment: I did as you said，but it‘s still not working. BTW, my sys is UEFI booted.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked for me with the same problem.

Go to System settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional drivers

When it shows you all drivers, in my case I had one checked from `Intel Corporation`: switch it off, by checking `Do not use this device` (or something similar).

Then reboot.

Credit: [Fix Dummy Output (no sound) Problem in Ubuntu 14.04 Lts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsPpm3gkFTw)

It worked for me with a 16.04 version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already switched from ubuntu to manjaro.