# Plugged-in headphone cannot be detected but bluetooth headphone works well

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, 19.10, headphones

I recently upgraded my system from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10, and I found a weird issue. When I physically plug a headphone in my laptop, I cannot find it everywhere, it seems like that it is not being detected. However, if I plug the same headphone into other devices, it works well and the headphone works well in Windows 10(dual system on the same PC).

What makes me confused is that if I use Bluetooth earphones in the laptop, it works quite well.
This problem occurs when I used Ubuntu 19.04 sometimes, but not frequently. However, when I switch to the 19.10, I can never detect my dear headphone :(.

The result of `lspci | grep Audio` is:

```
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

I tried several methods, such as running `sudo alsactl restore`, and it says:

```
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: No such file or directory
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "ATI R6xx HDMI" "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700" "0x17aa" "0x380d"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Conexant CX8070" "HDA:14f11f86,17aa3820,00100100" "0x17aa" "0x3815"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

I almost tried **every** methods that can be found, but **none** of them works.
Who can help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: I have the same problem with my laptop.
I also have the conexant cx8070 sound card and it doesn't seem supported

Answer (score 0):

After tried many solutions, I found this post today: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=315230, and it does work for me.

Simply speaking: Every time you switch your system from Windows to Linux, DON'T USE REBOOT, SHUTDOWN the whole system and restart will solve the problem.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

I would have asked you to elaborate a bit more, about which methods you have actually used to try and fix this. However, no rep...
I answer now, as I have the same sound card, and the same re-occurring problem, but on 18.04. However, the method seems quite drastic, but nothing else worked.

Following many other postings about nonfunctional headphone jacks I turned to remove `alsa` all the way, and reinstall it. Same for `linux-sound-base`. I am thinking, that the `--reinstall` could also work. Anyway:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

Be mindful, and check what packages were removed. An addtional

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

might be necessary.

Sometimes, a simple `alsactl restore` is enough. Or a `sudo alsa froce-reload`.

Please check this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1/464444#464444) if you are running a dual boot system.

Then please comment on what actually helped. I'd be interested.

Comment: Hey SpelAEnk, sorry for the late reply. I tried the approach you provided and unable the "hybrid shutdown/fast boot" in Windows. However, they didn't work too. I found this post: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=315230, and I find this work for me! Thank you for your reply!